# How to extend init method with inheritance

Tags: python

I have the following code, in which I am trying to extend the `init` method of `BaseExporter`:

```
from apps.ingest.platform_export import BaseExporter

class Vudu(BaseExporter):

    def __init__(self):
        BaseExporter.__init__()
        self.platform = ' Vudu'
```

Basically, I would like all of the init'd variables from the BaseExporter plus the additional variable of `self.platform = 'Vudu'`. How would I do this correctly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were on the right track, only missing self on the parent class

```
from apps.ingest.platform_export import BaseExporter

class Vudu(BaseExporter):

    def __init__(self):
        BaseExporter.__init__(self)
        self.platform = ' Vudu'
```

Comment: I believe using super is "more" correct - as the code will work even if the classes are refactored for multiple inheritance for instance.

Comment: I prefer to use the parent for each __init__ because it could have more than one argument even more with multiple inheritance

Comment: in which case you should use variable argument lists. Using super ensures that the Inheritance tree is always executed in the correct way.

Answer (score 8):

Python 3

```
from apps.ingest.platform_export import BaseExporter

class Vudu(BaseExporter):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.platform = ' Vudu'
```

Python 2

```
from apps.ingest.platform_export import BaseExporter

class Vudu(BaseExporter):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Vudu, self).__init__()
        self.platform = ' Vudu'
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, this is the old way to do things.

Comment: Or just   `super().__init__()`  if the OP is using  python3